# Easiest way to integrate an offline Leaderboard [LibGDX]

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Was just wondering what the easiest way is to integrate an offline leaderboard that keeps a score saves. For example lets say `score++` gives an extra point to `int score`, would you just make another `int highScore` with an `if (score > highScore){ highScore = score }` or some weird stuff

Comment: You could use a (SQLite) database for that purpose.

Comment: Don't do that. Totally overpowered approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way with LibGDX to implement an offline Leaderboard would be to use the cross-platform [`Preferences`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences).

```
Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("leaderboard");
Integer score = prefs.getInteger("highscore", 0); // if there is no highscore yet, the score will be 0

// gameplay logic...
Integer newScore = 1337;

if (newScore > score) {
    prefs.putInteger("highscore", score);
}
```

That's it. It should work on at least Desktop, Android and iOS and will be persisted so it can be retrieved also when the application is restarted.

Comment: Thanks, is there a specific location I need to place this type of Code? Never played around with Preferences before

Comment: Nope, Gdx.app.getPreferences is static. You can access that from anywhere in your code.